# How can I get regex syntax highlight for `new RegExp` in js in Vscode?

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

As the following shows, 
I want "regex syntax highlight for `new RegExp`", just as the regex literal. 
How can I do that?

[image: regex]

```js
/^this\b(.*?)\bis(:{0,1})/g; 

new RegExp(/*regex*/ `^this\b(.*?)\bis(:{0,1})`, 'g'); // << syntax higlight?
```

---

*Update*:

it was so obvious that this is a bad idea, and I didnt notice it: 
-- the **escape character `\`** in String has different meaning than in Regex Literal 
-- and so String *should not be* highlighted as Regex Literal (unless you really mean to & has a way to solve the `\` escape problem)

Comment: The answer might be: by submitting a feature request, and then waiting for (or possibly helping with) its approval and implementation...

Comment: I just thought there could be some extensions out there, something like es6-string-html

Comment: find the TextMate grammar for JavaScript, find the part that recognizes and colors a regex literal, find/add grammar to detect `new Regexp`, apply the same syntax coloring on the first argument if it is a string. Why is it a template string in your example?

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for the comment, I searched & tried with TextMate https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#injection-grammars , no idea why it just doesnt work at all.

Comment: @rioV8 I retried, and it works now, but the side effects of my way may be bad...

Answer (score 0):

*Update*:

it was so obvious that this is a bad idea, and I didnt notice it: 
-- the **escape character `\`** in String has different meaning than in Regex Literal 
-- and so String *should not be* highlighted as Regex Literal (unless you really mean to & has a way to solve the `\` escape problem)

---

#### preface

- again, Im not professional on this, 
  some of the steps are imperfect/redundant -- *especially for `source.js` overwrite* : 
  ***I have no idea what is the side effect of overwriting the default `TextMate rule`!!!!!*** 
  ***I have no idea what is the side effect of overwriting the default `TextMate rule`!!!!!*** 
  ***I have no idea what is the side effect of overwriting the default `TextMate rule`!!!!!***
- (if this doesnt work, Idk. )
- (*Update*)

  - this approach is ***buggy***, the brackets `{}` syntax highlight seems not paired, 
    seems its due to something wrong with the TextMate regex match rule of `` RegExp\((`|'|") ``
  - so, this post serves more of the purpose of: just giving an idea of how things works

#### shorter path

- if you dont want to bother too much of *setting up the vscode extension project by `yo code`* below, 
  just

  1. download the code from https://github.com/kirksl/so60384141 (`so60384141-master`) 
     this is an already setup vscode extension project 
     (*Im not the owner*)
  2. modify the `package.json` & `JavaScript.tmLanguage.json (js_new_regex_syntax_hlt.tmLanguage.json)` described below. 
     (be aware, the project name (or such) are different in this `package.json` vs the `package.json` described below)
  3. put that folder to your Vscode Extension folder `C:\Users\XXXX\.vscode\extensions`

#### detailed procedure

1. open a folder
2. run `npm install -g yo generator-code` 
   run `yo code` 
   select build `new Language Support` 
   ... (setup details omitted)
   finish setup, obtain a project -- a **Vscode extension project**, in a newly created folder, say `jsnr`

   eg: (folder name may not match)
   [image: yo code]
3. search online for `TextMate rule` for Javascript
   find https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/javascript/syntaxes/JavaScript.tmLanguage.json 
   get file `\syntaxes\JavaScript.tmLanguage.json`
4. create a new folder `syntaxes` in your extension project `jsnr` 
   put the file `JavaScript.tmLanguage.json` in `jsnr/syntaxes` 
   rename the file to `js_new_regex_syntax_hlt.tmLanguage.json`

   your folder structure should look like this: 
   [image: folder structure]
5. open file `js_new_regex_syntax_hlt.tmLanguage.json (JavaScript.tmLanguage.json)` 
   locate the place **where has the regex syntax for matching `regex literal in js`** (omitted some lines)

   ```json
           {
             "name": "string.regexp.js",
             "begin": "((?<![_$[:alnum:])\\]]|\\+\\+|--|}|\\*\\/)|((?<=^return|[^\\._$[:alnum:]]return|^case|[^\\._$[:alnum:]]case))\\s*)\\/(?![\\/*])(?=(?:[^\\/\\\\\\[]|\\\\.|\\[([^\\]\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\])+\\/([dgimsuy]+|(?![\\/\\*])|(?=\\/\\*))(?!\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_$]))",
             "beginCaptures": {
               "0": {
                 "name": "punctuation.definition.string.begin.js"
               }
             },
   ```
6. add your own regex matching rule that **matches for `new RegExp`**, below the above regex matching rule

   ```json
           {
             "name": "string.regexp.js",
             "begin": "RegExp\\((`|'|\")",
             "beginCaptures": {
               "0": {
                 "name": "punctuation.definition.string.begin.js"
               }
             },
             "end": "(`|'|\")",
             "endCaptures": {
               "1": {
                 "name": "punctuation.definition.string.end.js"
               }
             },
             "patterns": [
               {
                 "include": "#regexp"
               }
             ]
           }
   ```

   image for part of the file 
   [image: regex place]

   - (somehow a regex lookbehind doesnt work... )
7. open `package.json`

   modify to

   ```json
           "grammars": 
           [
               {
                 "scopeName": "source.js",
                 "path": "./syntaxes/js_new_regex_syntax_hlt.tmLanguage.json",
                 "injectTo": ["source"]
               }
           ]
   ```

   (full file):

   ```json
   {
     "name": "jsnrsh",
     "displayName": "js_new_regex_synhlt",
     "description": "syntax highlight for new RegExp in js",
     "version": "0.0.1",
     "engines": {
       "vscode": "^1.75.0"
     },
     "categories": [
       "Programming Languages"
     ],
     "contributes": {
           "grammars": 
           [
               {
                 "scopeName": "source.js",
                 "path": "./syntaxes/js_new_regex_syntax_hlt.tmLanguage.json",
                 "injectTo": ["source"]
               }
           ]
     }
   }
   ```

   - this **injects(/overwrites)** your `TextMate rule` into Vscode's default rule

     - `TextMate rule` defines what text segment is under what `TextMate scope`
     - `TextMate scope` is used for determine which word use what color of syntax higlight
     - (by default, Vscode knows how to automatically highlight the code,, base on the `TextMate rule`, 
       but you can still create your own syntax highlight color, by changing the `textMateRules`.

       eg:

       ```json
         "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
           "textMateRules": [
             {
               "scope": "keyword.todo",
               "settings": {
                   "foreground": "#9a9c2b"
               }
             }
           ]
         },
       ```
   - again, Im not professional on this, 
     ***I have no idea what is the side effect of overwriting the default `TextMate rule`!!!!!***
8. now, the extension project is done -- with `package.json` & `js_new_regex_syntax_hlt.tmLanguage.json (JavaScript.tmLanguage.json)` properly set.

   copy the `jsnr` to where the Vscode extension folder is --eg: `C:\Users\XXXX\.vscode\extensions`
9. reload your Vscode, open any js file 
   -- now `new RegExp` has regex syntax highlight too

   [image: result]

   - (this makes the syntax highlight lag on vscode start up -- the `RegExp` class appears to be red, then turns back into green later. idk why.)

#### more info

<sub>> javascript - How can I get regex syntax highlight for `new RegExp` in js in Vscode? - Stack Overflow 
> [How can I get regex syntax highlight for `new RegExp` in js in Vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75472191/how-can-i-get-regex-syntax-highlight-for-new-regexp-in-js-in-vscode?noredirect=1#comment133162690_75472191) 
>
> javascript - VS Code - highlight some variables with TextMate - Stack Overflow 
> [VS Code - highlight some variables with TextMate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631153/vs-code-highlight-some-variables-with-textmate) 
>
> Can one VS Code syntax scope reference another for theme purposes? - Stack Overflow 
> [Can one VS Code syntax scope reference another for theme purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66831942/can-one-vs-code-syntax-scope-reference-another-for-theme-purposes) 
>
> design patterns - VSCode: TextMate Regex in User Settings - Stack Overflow 
> [VSCode: TextMate Regex in User Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52025424/vscode-textmate-regex-in-user-settings) 
>
> Syntax Highlight Guide | Visual Studio Code Extension API 
> https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide 
>
> Contribution Points | Visual Studio Code Extension API 
> https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.languages 
>
> Visual Studio Code Themes 
> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_editor-syntax-highlighting 
>
> VSCode/TextMate syntax highlighting grammar -- matching code until end of line - Stack Overflow 
> [VSCode/TextMate syntax highlighting grammar -- matching code until end of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70509807/vscode-textmate-syntax-highlighting-grammar-matching-code-until-end-of-line) 
>
> How to make your own VS Code theme! - YouTube 
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pGzssFNtWXw 
>
> // 
>
> How can I find the folder of the theme I'm using in VS Code - Stack Overflow 
> [How can I find the folder of the theme I'm using in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63455950/how-can-i-find-the-folder-of-the-theme-im-using-in-vs-code) 
>
> How to edit default dark theme for Visual Studio Code? - Stack Overflow 
> [How to edit default dark theme for Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35165362/how-to-edit-default-dark-theme-for-visual-studio-code) 
>
> vscode-textmate/javascript-regex.json at main · microsoft/vscode-textmate 
> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-textmate/blob/main/test-cases/first-mate/fixtures/javascript-regex.json 
>
> vscode/Regular Expressions (JavaScript).tmLanguage at main · microsoft/vscode 
> https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/javascript/syntaxes/Regular%20Expressions%20(JavaScript).tmLanguage 
>
> VS Code: Injection grammar scope for custom keyword is overriden in C++ - Stack Overflow 
> [VS Code: Injection grammar scope for custom keyword is overriden in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70397002/vs-code-injection-grammar-scope-for-custom-keyword-is-overriden-in-c) 
>
> Create Custom Syntax Highlighting in VS Code | Programming Language | Software Coding Tutorials - YouTube 
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5msZv-nKebI 
>
> How to inject a TextMate grammar to a Markdown heading in VS Code? - Stack Overflow 
> [How to inject a TextMate grammar to a Markdown heading in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633579/how-to-inject-a-textmate-grammar-to-a-markdown-heading-in-vs-code) 
>
> vscode extensions - Create Custom Language in Visual Studio Code - Stack Overflow 
> [Create Custom Language in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687783/create-custom-language-in-visual-studio-code) 
>
> visual studio code - How to reference an injected grammar within a custom VSCode language - Stack Overflow 
> [How to reference an injected grammar within a custom VSCode language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60384141/how-to-reference-an-injected-grammar-within-a-custom-vscode-language) 
>
> kirksl/so60384141: How to reference an injected grammar within a custom VSCode language 
> https://github.com/kirksl/so60384141 
>
> // 
>
> ~~// themes - VSCode color customisation, Include regexp check in textMateRules - Stack Overflow 
> ~~// [VSCode color customisation, Include regexp check in textMateRules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69414641/vscode-color-customisation-include-regexp-check-in-textmaterules) 
> ~~// 
> ~~// Highlight - Visual Studio Marketplace 
> ~~// https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight 
> ~~// 
> ~~// Semantic Highlight Guide | Visual Studio Code Extension API 
> ~~// https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide 
> ~~// 
> ~~// vscode extensions - What is the VS Code TextMate syntax for JSON inside an HTML attribute - Stack Overflow 
> ~~// [What is the VS Code TextMate syntax for JSON inside an HTML attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69239857/what-is-the-vs-code-textmate-syntax-for-json-inside-an-html-attribute) 
> ~~// 
> ~~// filmgirl/TextMate-Themes: A Collection of TextMate Themes I've gathered over the years 
> ~~// https://github.com/filmgirl/TextMate-Themes 
> ~~// 
> ~~// json-in-html/script-json.embedded.json at baseline · bahrus/json-in-html 
> ~~// https://github.com/bahrus/json-in-html/blob/baseline/syntax/script-json.embedded.json 
> ~~// 
> ~~// MagicPython/MagicRegExp.tmLanguage at master · MagicStack/MagicPython 
> ~~// https://github.com/MagicStack/MagicPython/blob/master/grammars/MagicRegExp.tmLanguage</sub>

Comment: you have it working now, why don't you create a pull request on the VSC repo so we all benefit of this feature

Comment: @rioV8 - The issue is stated in the post. -- > Im not professional on this, ***I have no idea what is the side effect of overwriting the default `TextMate rule`!!!!!*** - It will be helpful if someone knows what Im doing and can do better. \ - If you know a place where people knows how to do these things, you can link this post to it.

Comment: fork the VSC repo on github, create a branch `feature-js-regexp-string`, use `.` to start VSC web, edit the file `extensions/javascript/syntaxes/JavaScript.tmLanguage.json`, create a commit with the update, create a pull request for this commit